# What are the triggers for the inner circle quests?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I've done a few companion quests already, but there are some companions where I didn't get any quests so far. I'm beyond Skyhold and already finished one of the two main quests after that point.

I'm wondering if I missed certain triggers for some companions, or maybe I simply didn't have a high enough approval with them. I'm also wondering how the generic collection quests available for some companions (e.g. Red lyrium for Varric and Warden stuff for Backwall) relate to the actual companion quests. I got the companion quest for Varric before even fulfilling the Red lyrium quests, so I'd assume they are unrelated.

So how do I unlock each companion quest exactly? I'd appreciate reasonably spoiler-free answers, as far as that is possible in this case.

Comment: I got Cassandra's actual companion quest before I finished hunting down all her targets, so I don't think they are actually related.

Answer (score 2):

According to the game guide that I have (Prima, I believe, but it's at home right now), the companion quests are unlocked once you have reached the requisite approval threshold with that specific companion.  Further, the collection quests do not contribute directly to this, but they do help you to get more approval and if you have the companion with whose collection quest it is, you gain a greater amount of approval.